# Method called in -viewWillLayoutSubviews inexplicably runs twice

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've got the following code in a detail view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self configureView];
}
```

When I segue to this view controller with a breakpoint on first line of `-configureView`, it appears that `[self configureView]` is called twice. However:

- Both times the method is hit, the stack looks like this:

[image: stack]

- When I comment `[self configureView]` in the above code, it's hit zero times.
- As evident by the stack being the same both times, `-configureView` does not call itself recursively.
- `-configureView` is only called in the above code.

Comment: So `viewWillLayoutSubviews` gets called twice? Then the question is what is triggering a re-layout in your view controller right?

Comment: Yeah, good point. The question is, why is `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` being called twice. In the exactly same way on the stack.

Answer (score 11):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent.

Given `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called whenever the `bounds` change on the controller's view, there's no guarantee that it'll be invoked once only. It'll be called whenever rotation occurs for example.

Your `configureView` method is probably better called from somewhere else, perhaps in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` or even a custom mutator for `BirdDetail` item as per [Hermann's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14946716/840428).

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the usual patterns then configureView is called in the setter of `detailItem`. Check the setter method. And `[detailViewController setDetailItem:something]` is often called in `prepareForSegue:`.

The key point is: does it matter?

Comment: I call it in `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` because I want the values to update from the model any time the views are laid out. Calling it in the setter makes more structural sense, but leads to the views not being updated before a segue, leading to the presentation of stale data. Anyway yes, it seems to most certainly matter! For one thing, I'd like to understand the behavior. Also, what if I wanted an intensive operation in this method? Why should it execute twice?

Comment: I did not say that you have to call it from the setter. I just want to give the hint that you may actually call it from the setter too which might cause it being called twice. That's all. However, I am not convinced that this is an appropriate place to refresh the data from the model. viewWillAppear should be sufficient for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Hermann! I will take a look report here. I am thinking about how quote, "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs..." by Knuth (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). I'm just trying to make sure I understand how all these methods hook into the runtime. Thanks for pointing out `viewWillAppear`